# Why is my for loop in C working correctly?

Tags: c, cs50

So I have this code I created for CS50 pset1 Mario problem. The code is behaving correctly and is doing exactly what it is supposed to do, but I don't understand one of the parts. Why is it behaving this way.

Here's the code I have written in C:

```
  #include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void){
int height, row, space, hash;

    do {
        printf("Height: ");
        height = get_int();
    } while(height<0 || height>23);

    for (row=0; row<height; row++){

        for (space=height-(row+1); space>0; space--){
            printf("-");
        }

        for (hash=height-row; hash<=height; hash++){
            printf("#");
        }

        printf("#\n");
    }

}
```

So for example when the user enters 3 as the Height, I get

> ```
> --##
> -###
> ####
> ```

What I don't understand why it is not:

> ```
> --####
> -###
> ##
> ```

This part is what is throwing me off:

```
for (hash=height-row; hash<=height; hash++){
            printf("#");
        }
```

If hash = height-row then shouldn't it be 3-0=3 and have it print the hash sign 3 times? Then 3-1=2 and print it twice, and so on? Why is it doing it in reverse?

Can someone please explain what's wrong with my logic?

Comment: Please run this in a debugger first :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is in the conditional and the increment part of the for loop.

You are correct that the initial value of hash would be 3. The conditional part of the for loop will check to make sure hash (3) is less than or equal to height (3). So, is 3 <= 3 ? Yes.

The increment part of the for loop determines what changes in each iteration. In you case, hash will be incremented by 1, so the next time the loop is executed, hash will have a value of 4. The conditional will check: is hash (4) <= height (3)? This returns false, and the for loop will be terminated.

When the next iteration of the "row" loop happens, the initial value of hash is 2 (since 3 - 1 = 2). This will continue to add 1 to hash until "hash <= height" returns false. As "row" increases, more "#" get printed.

Comment: Now it makes sense. Thanks for explaining.

Answer (score 2):

Let's break down the for loop:

```
     for (hash=height-row; hash<=height; hash++){
        printf("#");
        }
```

When height is 3:

```
for row = 0 (less than 3):
    for (hash = 3 - 0; hash <= 3 (true); hash++ (hash will be 4 next iteration))
        print #
```

Next,

```
    for (has = 4; hash <= 3 (false); hash ++)
        (does not print #)
```

and finally,

```
    print #\n
```

You get two hashes total, e.g.

```
--##
```